# Erro para importar tabela mysql no phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estou com um problema para importar uma tabela no phpmyadmin.

**Tabela:**

```
CREATE TABLE ManterEmpresa ( 

  IdEmpresa INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  CNPJ INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  NomeEmpresa VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

  Logo VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

  Descricao VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

  Endereco VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

  Telefone VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

**Erro:**

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')ENGINE = INNODB' at line 9

Como posso resolver este meu problema ?

Comment: Em `Telefone VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,` remova a virgula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa linha

```
Telefone VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
```

deveria ser

```
Telefone VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Eu também definiria o `Id` como chave primária.

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira eu também, mas isso não tem nada a ver com o erro.

Comment: Não com esse erro, mas definir um auto increment sem uma PK dispara um 1075. Acho que ia ser um bom complemento pra resposta

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo

Comment: @EwertonSimonetto você pode votar positivamente nas respostas e também escolher a que resolveu o seu problema marcando o sinal abaixo das setinhas para votar.

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira Ele pode ter diminuído o script para colocar aqui. É possível definir um `index` como `auto_increment`, mesmo que não seja `primary key`